# how to solve "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I have  some problem in my program. Line number 93 has a error. How to resolve this?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at first_JWNL.main(first_JWNL.java:93)
```

### Code

```
 for (int i=0;i<sentences.length;i++)
             {  
                 System.out.println(i);
              System.out.println(sentences[i]);
              int wcount = sentences[i].split("\\s+").length;
        String[] word1 = sentences[i].split(" ");


        for (int j=0;j<wcount;j++){  
            System.out.println(j);

         System.out.println(word1[j]);
         String sen="one";

         IndexWordSet set = wordnet.lookupAllIndexWords(word1[j]);
         IndexWord[] ws = set.getIndexWordArray(); 
         **POS p = ws[0].getPOS();**///////Line no 93

         Set<String> synonyms = new HashSet<String>();
         IndexWord indexWord = wordnet.lookupIndexWord(p, word1[j]);
         Synset[] synSets = indexWord.getSenses();
         for (Synset synset : synSets)
         {  Word[] words = synset.getWords();

            for (Word word : words)
            {  synonyms.add(word.getLemma());
            }
         }
         System.out.println(synonyms);
```

Comment: Is that `POS` actually in the code, or did you add that to show us where position 93 was?

Comment: IndexWord[] ws does this have data? check length of it

Comment: `first_JWNL.java:93`  Which is line 93?  No, instead.. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: At which line you getting this exception?

Answer (score 0):

do a check :

```
if(ws.length > 0){
  POS p = ws[0].getPOS();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `set.getIndexWordArray ()` returns empty array for some reason.  You didn't post the code of this method, so I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
IndexWordSet set = wordnet.lookupAllIndexWords(word1[j]);
```

cannot find any index words in the array, and returns an empty set. Thus

```
IndexWord[] ws = set.getIndexWordArray();
```

returns a zero length array, and the expression

```
ws[0]
```

causes the Exception.

You have to take into consideration that there may be no matches.

For example, in your code, do something like this:

```
if (wordnet.size() == 0 ) {
    System.out.println("Could not find any words!!!!!");
} else {
    IndexWordSet set = wordnet.lookupAllIndexWords(word1[j]);
    IndexWord[] ws = set.getIndexWordArray(); 
    POS p = ws[0].getPOS();

    // .......
    // ETC
    // ....... 

}
```